# What happens when I go to localhost in a browser without specifying a port?

Tags: network-programming, operating-system, localhost, port

I understand what happens when I specify a port. But what happens when I don't? It makes no sense to me since while doing development, my local grails server picks up requests from `localhost` without any port specification, despite that it's supposed to be on port 8080.

So what happens when you just go to `localhost` in a browser with no port? What controls where the request goes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't specify the protocol it assumes HTTP.
This standard defines URI: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

If you don't specify the port, it assumes port 80.

If no server is listening in port 80, the browser will receive a RST at TCP level when it tries to establish a TCP connection (below HTTP layer). You will see a message like "Connection Refused".